# How to get the ID of MATLAB handle object?

Tags: oop, matlab, object, handle

The problem comes when I am trying to use [MATLAB handle objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/handle.html) as key values in [MATLAB containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/containers_map.html).

`ld( h1, h2 )` defines a linear order on handle objects, so there should be no limitation on using handle objects as key values for maps, however only integer or string types are allowed.

A workaround for this problem could be retrieving the actual ids (addresses) of handle objects (which are basically being compared in `ld` function).

So the question is: how to get the ID of a handle object?

---

**Found out that a workaround can be done** using persistent variables in static member functions.

In this case you should inherit all your classes from a base class like the following.

```
classdef object < handle
properties ( GetAccess = 'public', SetAccess = 'private' )
    id
end

methods ( Access = 'protected' )
    function obj = object()
        obj.id = object.increment();
    end
end

methods ( Static, Access = 'private' )
    function result = increment()
        persistent stamp;
        if isempty( stamp )
            stamp = 0;
        end
        stamp = stamp + uint32(1);
        result = stamp;
    end
end
```

end

Comment: you probably mean not `ld` but relational operator `lt`, i.e. `lower then`?

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of something like object `HashCode` in Java/C# applied to MATLAB OO. If you get address of a MATLAB object (type `format debug` in the command window) it is still not reasonable to use it because it will not stay same unlike in C++ but will be moved by system (managed memory).

You could manually implement an interface `getHashCode()` for your MATLAB objects. Unlike traditional hashcode you must make sure that your hashcode is **always** different for different objects - not a simple task!

MATLAB default comparer function `sort` apparently uses internally the object hashcode but this will not help you here - comparing objects is actually an orthogonal concept to their hashcode.