# MATLAB - How to compare if two objects are the same or different

Tags: matlab, oop, object

In C++ I would just compare the memory addresses of both objects. How would I do something similar in MATLAB?

Worst Case would be to have a static variable that iterates in each constructor and every object gets the current value as ID. But is there a better solution?

Thank you in advance.

@Edit:
I'd like to extend this question by assuming I have some given/not changeable **classes inheriting handle** and **overloading eq**. If I want to **compare two objects of this class** can I somehow **cast both instances to handle** and use the implementation of eq of the super class?

Comment: Just to be clear: you are specifically asking about matlab classes, right?

Comment: Yes, did I explain/say something wrong?

Comment: No, no, but a lot of people think that matrices/structures/cells in MATLAB behave as classes and think that `A=ones(3); B=A` , `B` and `A` are the same, and they are not. Just making clear you where not confused with that, and you where talking about specifically [MATLABs oop](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html).

Comment: No, ah okay, I am talking about matlabs oop.

Answer (score 3):

To test that two handle objects `a` and `b` refer to the same instance, you only need to use `a == b`. This is the same as `eq(a, b)`. This is the [defined behaviour of `==` for handle objects](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.relationaloperators.html). I.e., for handle objects, `==` tests for equality of instances, not equality of the values within the instances. This is different from value objects.

For this to work you need to be using handle objects (`classdef myObject < handle`) because it doesn't make sense to test instances of value objects.

N.B. if you also need to get some kind of instance identifier for a handle object, then you need to do something like you describe using a persistent variable. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446442/how-to-get-the-id-of-matlab-handle-object). In that case I would make that a base class for all your objects, so you wouldn't have to copy the same code into each class. But that's unnecessary if all you want to do is test two instances.